# how to execute some initialization code in a war package in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I'm using a framework to deal with some request, now, I can start it from a main function like this:

```
public Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            //init the framework
            Init initer = new Init();
            initer.initFramework();
            
            //start my besiness code below
        }
    }
```

now I need to package my project in a war format and put it into tomcat, how can I be able to excute the initialization code?

Comment: You should specify if this Init framework is public or internal framework? And if this is general or some framework specific question?

Answer (score 5):

When you start a war-file in Tomcat using servlet 2.3 or higher you can use the `web.xml` file to declare *listeners*.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>test.MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This listener should implement the `ServletContextListener` interface. Listeners gets notified of lifecycle changes (such as when the servlet context has been initialized). The listener can be implemented to run your initialization code as illustrated below:

```
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        Init initer = new Init();
        initer.initFramework();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // destroy stuff
    }
}
```

If you are running the war-file in a servlet 3 environment there might not even be a `web.xml` file. In that case the `@WebListener` annotation can be used to indicate that your component should be called. The JavaDoc for `@WebListener` can be found [here](http://javadox.com/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) but basically what you need to do is to add the annotation to your listener.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement **org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer** and that's it, no xml.

Comment: That's a great solution if the OP uses Spring!